# Problem with Redux Thunk ( could not run function in reducer)

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I have a problem with redux-thunk (redux-toolkit) , when I dispatch action logIn, console.log is working but this function `Auth` in `apiInstance.ts` file is not working

Here are my set up store and reducer

```
// my config's store
import { ThunkAction, thunk } from "redux-thunk";
import { Action, configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import rootReducer from "../reducer/index.ts";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware(), thunk],
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type AppThunk = ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, Action<any>>;
export default store;
```

```
// my store 
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import AuthReducer from "./auth/index.ts";
import PathVariableReducer from "./pathVariable/index.ts";
import codeRunner from "./codeRunner/index.ts";
import toastMessage from "./toastMessage/index.ts";
import dataDefine from "./dataDefine.ts";
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  AuthReducer,
  PathVariableReducer,
  codeRunner,
  toastMessage,
  dataDefine,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

```
// my reducer

import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import {
  Auth,
  LogOut,
  ResetPasswordEmail,
  UpdateInfor,
} from "../../../service/apiInstance";


const AuthReducer = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    logIn: (state, action) => {
      console.log("test") // working
      Auth(action.payload, "login"); // not working
    },
    logOut: (state, action) => LogOut(),
    register: (state, action) => Auth(action.payload, "register"),
    forgotPassword: (state, action) =>
      ResetPasswordEmail({ email: action.payload }),
    resetPassword: (state, action) =>
      ResetPasswordEmail({
        oldPassword: action.payload,
        newPassword: action.payload,
      }),
    updateInfor: (state, action) => UpdateInfor(action.payload),
  },
});
```

and this is my function `Auth` in `apiInstance.ts`

```
// not working
import axios from "axios";
import { TOAST_MESSAGE } from "../redux/reducer/toastMessage";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
import { AppDispatch, AppThunk } from "../redux/store";
import { getPostSuccess } from "../redux/reducer/dataDefine";

export const Auth = (req: object, auth: string): AppThunk => async ( // my function
  dispatch: AppDispatch
) => {
  console.log("test successful");
  await fetchCSRFToken();
  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.post(`/${auth}`, req);
    localStorage.setItem("login", "true");
    localStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify(response.data.name));
    localStorage.setItem("email", JSON.stringify(response.data.email));
    window.location.replace("/");
    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(getPostSuccess);
    dispatch(
      TOAST_MESSAGE({
        type: "error",
        content: error,
        duration: 5,
      })
    );
    throw new Error("Authentication failed");
  }
};
```

I'm trying any case but it's not working, so what should I do in this case?